# How to convert Oracle to Sql server (SSM)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

Here is the Query

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE (F.COUNTRY,
    'null',
     NULL,
     1,
     0,
     'i') COUNTRY from Table
```

I need to convert the above oracle query to sql query (SSM).

Comment: SSMS is just a client tool. There are no regular expressions in SQL Server. What you typed has no regular expression pattern anyway, it's a direct replacement of the `'null'` string with another string. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes i'm Aware, I intent to ask for Sql query. We don't have RegExp_Replace in sql i believe, what will be the alternate for that function in sql is my question.

Comment: There isn't a direct alternative. SQL Server does not have regular expressions.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Replace the first occurence of `NULL` with `i`?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm trying to replace the value 'null' With NULL and and 'i' indicates it should be case insensitive comparison and for all ocurrences.

Comment: Are you using a case sensitive collation? Pretty sure you can just use replace for what you are describing.

Comment: @SeanLange, ya I tried , i'm just stuck with the syntactical representation of the query in Sql

Comment: It should be a simple as `replace(F.COUNTRY, 'null', NULL)`. But this will mean you get NULL for the entire tuple. If you instead want an empty string replace the literal NULL with ''

Comment: @SeanLange Great ! thanks, what about the case insensitive comparison? 'i' and the occurrences 0 and 1??

Comment: Are you using a case sensitive collation? If so, just wrap the column in LOWER. Not sure what you mean about occurrences 0 and 1??

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #str
(
    nstr NVARCHAR(200)
);

INSERT INTO #str VALUES('abc 123');
INSERT INTO #str VALUES('null');
INSERT INTO #str VALUES('Value ''null'' is NULL');
INSERT INTO #str VALUES('Null');
INSERT INTO #str VALUES('NULL');

-- general, first instance
SELECT nstr, STUFF(nstr, CHARINDEX('null', nstr), LEN('null'), 'NULL') FROM #str

-- ofc if you are strictly replacing the string 'null' with NULL, you don't need regular expression
SELECT nstr, new_nstr = (CASE WHEN nstr = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE nstr END) FROM #str

-- replace won't work
SELECT nstr, replace_nstr = replace(nstr, 'null', NULL) FROM #str
```